# Calculating the gain ratio between two images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Do you know any simple algorithm to calculate the gain ratio between two images? Do I have to compare pixel by pixel and actually know they are overlapping pixels, or is there a way by looking at the histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are of the same scene and only the gain varied then just the ratio of the average pixel value would be enough.

You might want to do this for a range of regions in the image to handle saturated pixels, and take the median of the ratios of each pair of regions.

Comment: Would that work for frames of a video? How would you define these regions?